# Can't install Xcode 7 via App Store

Tags: xcode

When I try to upgrade to the latest Xcode (7) from the App Store I get an error message that I should try again from the Purchased tab, which I do and still get the same error message.

Any clues how to fix this? How do I remove Xcode completely so I can start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https: //developer.apple.com/downloads/

This require Apple ID.